# Whom did you meet?

Tags: word-usage, sentence

I am confused to use the word "whom" in a sentence.Is the above sentence correct?
Give me a bit of your mind at what contexts we generally use whom with proper examples.

Answer (score 0):

A.  -you met someone
A.I.-did you meet someone? (here 'someone' is object of verb)
when we ask about 'someone' in a question  we can use 'who/whom' which functions as object of verb.
so 'whom/who did you meet' is correct.
whom did you meet -(formal)
who did you meet  -(informal)

Comment: _Who did you meet_: informal Mmmm...